# Convert AWG to Inches

Tags: code-golf, conversion, electrical-engineering

[AWG (American Wire Gauge)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) is a common way of specifying wire sizes. Your task in this challenge is to convert from a given gauge to the diameter of the wire in inches.

The size in inches for the gauges from `4/0` to `40` are shown in the table below:

### Gauge to inches table

```
| AWG | Diameter (Inches) |
|-----|-------------------|
| 4/0 | 0.46              |
| 3/0 | 0.4096            |
| 2/0 | 0.3648            |
| 1/0 | 0.3249            |
| 1   | 0.2893            |
| 2   | 0.2576            |
| 3   | 0.2294            |
| 4   | 0.2043            |
| 5   | 0.1819            |
| 6   | 0.162             |
| 7   | 0.1443            |
| 8   | 0.1285            |
| 9   | 0.1144            |
| 10  | 0.1019            |
| 11  | 0.0907            |
| 12  | 0.0808            |
| 13  | 0.072             |
| 14  | 0.0641            |
| 15  | 0.0571            |
| 16  | 0.0508            |
| 17  | 0.0453            |
| 18  | 0.0403            |
| 19  | 0.0359            |
| 20  | 0.032             |
| 21  | 0.0285            |
| 22  | 0.0253            |
| 23  | 0.0226            |
| 24  | 0.0201            |
| 25  | 0.0179            |
| 26  | 0.0159            |
| 27  | 0.0142            |
| 28  | 0.0126            |
| 29  | 0.0113            |
| 30  | 0.01              |
| 31  | 0.00893           |
| 32  | 0.00795           |
| 33  | 0.00708           |
| 34  | 0.0063            |
| 35  | 0.00561           |
| 36  | 0.005             |
| 37  | 0.00445           |
| 38  | 0.00397           |
| 39  | 0.00353           |
| 40  | 0.00314           |
```

### Clarifications

- For gauges less than `0`, you can take the input as either `3/0` or `000`
- You only have to support from the given `4/0` to `40`
- The [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) has some helpful formulas you can try to use if you don't want to hardcode everything
- Output your answers to at least 3 sig-figs
- This [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in **bytes** wins!

Comment: It's amazing what Americans can do to avoid using the metric system :-P

Comment: This isn't kolmogorov-complexity as it is a conversion to output and not a constant output

Comment: Can we take input as an array? `0000` as `[0, 0, 0, 0]` and `40` as `[40]`

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>33</s> 26 bytes

```
0.46%92^39%~*@".{3+".,~1-#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#@5@mYGulYKBnYqZqaRRnbKlap@WgpFdtrK2kp1NnqKvMxZWanJGvoGGdpqlmp6BuAATq1uowEkQAsSEQGwGxsSWQMDFQ//8fAA)

Takes input as a string with gauges less than zero as a string of zeroes. Finds the index of that string and divides 0.46 (the diameter of `0000`) by the 39th root of 92 (the ratio between gauges) that many times.

### Explanation

```
0.46%92^39%~*@".{3+".,~1-#  Input: string S
                         #  Length of S
                       1-   Subtract it from 1
                   ".,~     Eval S and append it, forms [1-len(S), eval(S)]
                 3+         Add 3 to each
            *@".            Sign of the eval
                {           Use that to index into the previous list
        39%~                Divide by 39
     92^                    Raise 92 to that power
0.46%                       Divide 0.46 by that and return
```

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES7), 36 bytes

```
s=>.46/92**(((+s||1-s.length)+3)/39)
```

Takes input in "0000" format.

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + GNU utils, 47

```bash
bc -l<<<"e(l(92)*(36-(${1/\/0/*-1+1}))/39)/200"
```

Straightforward arithmetic expression evaluation using `bc`.  Input given as a command-line parameter.

Gauges less than 0 are given as `n/0`.  The bash parameter expansion `${1/\/0/*-1+1}` converts these to -ve numbers and adds one which makes the arithmetic come out right.

`bc -l` gives 20 decimal places by default.  `bc`'s exponentiation operator `^` can only handle integer exponents so `ln(y*e(x))` is used instead.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#DcFBCoMwEAXQfU/xEReJMpkZDQUxR@mqNZWCGNDuQs4efe@bDqz47cjeOS0syOqclzJjSQ/czvgHEdq1vj@gLYTQRLOZabCdGZ9k2qz8YuGOtNdiLY@T5UGkqUvaY70A).

Comment: Maybe mention that the output values lack the leading zero or add it yourself? As a side note, there is also the possibility to solve this directly in a bc script, though in more bytes.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
VoLC$+3÷39µ92*.46÷
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x@W7@Osom18eLux5aGtlkZaeiZmh7f///9f3cRAHQA)**

A monadic link taking a tring and returning a number. The `'0...0'` cases produce some extra output, but the return value is correct, as may be seen by ignoring the first two lines [here](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#Nc4xCgIxEEbhywgBFdmZiaupba0FEc/gGbTxEJ5AEDsJ2yYncS8S5y0Y9k/1vrDtcNnvZgur2VL5JJ2vYl9zq/fx9irP7/AYr9m/8j62dgqdn7AM/5vLJz71mS/61r7et/FtfYlmCimFVGiFWKiFXOgFIAhF6PQ2QhGKUIQiFKEIRRjCEDb9DsIQhjCEIQxhiNiF8w8).

#### How?

```
VoLC$+3÷39µ92*.46÷ - Main link: guageString
V                  - evaluate as Jelly code (a string of zeros evaluates to 0)
    $              - last two links as a monad
  L                -     length
   C               -     complement (1-length)
 o                 - Or (integer value for > 0, 1-lenght for strings of zeros)
     +3            - add 3
       ÷39         - divide by 39
          µ        - monadic chain separation (call the result p)
              .46÷ - 0.46 divided by
           92*     - 92 raised to the power of p
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda s:.46/92**((3+(int(s)or 1-len(s)))/39)
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqhQbKVnYqZvaaSlpaFhrK2RmVeiUayZX6RgqJuTmgdkamrqG1tq/k8DChUrZOYpRKsbAIG6jjqMVI9V0FaILi4p0sjUVAApywQpK0rMS0/VMDHUjLXi4iwoAhmrXm1gZVKrrgdUk5sIskVHIQ1kAUxe8z8A)**

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>25</s> 23 bytes

```
8Ø50/92ID1‹ig(>}3+39/m/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@29xeIapgb6lkaeL4aOGnZnpGna1xtrGlvq5@v//GxgYAAA)

**Explanation**

```
8Ø                       # push the 8th prime (0-indexed) = 23
  50/                    # divide by 50 = 0.46
     92                  # push 92
       I                 # push input
        D1‹i   }         # if input < 1
            g(>          # calculate -len(input)+1
                3+       # add 3
                  39/    # divide by 39
                     m   # raise 92 to this power
                      /  # divide 0.46 by this
```

Answer (score 0):

## Excel, <s>53</s> 49 bytes

```
=92^((36-IF(ISNUMBER(A1),A1,49-CODE(A1)))/39)/200
```

Takes gauges less than Zero as String (1/0, 2/0 etc.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 39 + 1 (-p) = 40 bytes

```perl
s/(.).0/1-$1/e;$_=.005*92**((36-$_)/39)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFLCoAgEADQy7hQYX7JBBIdoTO4chFEDtn5m96z/lzqPiliQiaBINS30HZk1lyXnGMsK4SWqNTkLsTfsPcc93Q4FFnYwX4)

Takes the bigger gauges as "n/0".